# Maclaurin series expansion of $\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am trying to figure out the Maclaurin Series expansion of the function, preferribly in a sneaky and clever way. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can check Newton's binomial theorem

Comment: Why clever? Differentiation is easy.

Comment: Our teacher hasn't "taught" us differentiation yet, so we can't use it on tests and such. We have to find other roundabout ways of doing things.

Comment: I want to say Cauchy Product, but I'm not sure it will be sneaky nor clever :)

Answer (score 4):

set
$$
F(x)=\frac1{(1-x)^n} = \prod_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k
$$
here the coefficient of $x^m$ is the number of ways of expressing $m$ as a sum of $n$ non-negative integers, with order significant (i.e. $3+4+5$ and $4+3+5$ are different expressions).

this is just the number of ways of fitting $n-1$ separators into $m$ slots, i.e. $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$
so:
$$
\frac1{(1+x)^n}=F(-x)=1-nx+\frac{n(n+1)}{2!}x^2-...
$$

Comment: thx, i'll put in the $x^2$! the $j$ is a dummy, but you can't just interchange sum and product operations

Comment: Oh my goodness... I can't believe I wrote what I did. :o  Yeah... $(a+b)(c+d)\neq ac + bd$. Oops.  It works for sums. :P

Comment: i do the same - i call it 'logic circuit fail'.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost the $n^{\rm th}$ derivative of $1/(1+x)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that computing the derivatives is really the easiest way (as pointed out By Andre Nicolas). Your function is

$$
f(x) = (1+x)^{-n}\,.
$$

Now differentiate:
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(x) &=& -n (1+x)^{-(n+1)} \\
f''(x) &=& (-1)^2 n(n+1) (1+x)^{-(n+2)}\,.
\end{eqnarray}
By now the general pattern should be clear:

$$
f^{(k)} (x) = (-1)^k \, n (n+1) \cdots (n+k-1) \, (1+x)^{-n+k}.
$$

Evaluating the above at $x=0$ you get the following Maclaurin series (convergent for $|x|<1$)

$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k\, x^k$$

with

$$
a_k = \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} = (-1)^k \frac{ n (n+1) \cdots (n+k-1)}{k!} = (-1)^k \left ( \begin{array}{c} n+k-1\\ k \end{array} \right ).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Simple, yet not straightforward, approach:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^n} &= (1-x)^{-n} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-n}{k}(-x)^k\tag 1 \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\left((-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}\right)(-x)^k\tag2 \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^k \\
\end{align}

We arrive at $(1)$ using the binomial series, and at $(2)$ using the relationship between the multiset coefficient and the binomial coefficient $\binom{-n}{k}$.